# PHP fill array with sum of mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sum

I am kind of a novice in programming. I am trying to create an array from a MySQL table, which I will use later to create a graph in PHP/Javascript.

The entire idea is, that I want to make an array, filled with data representing every week of the year. So, an array with 52 entries (lets forget the 53'rd week which occurs sometimes).

My database:

I have 1 table in my database which I use for this:

```
+-------------------------+
I       production        I
+-------------------------+
I  Shift     I  (number)  I <-ranging from 1 to 3 (different shifts people make)
I  Line      I  (number)  I <-ranging from 1-8 (different 'conveyor belts')
I  Products  I  (number)  I <-ranging from 0- a lot! (To be entered in a form)
I  Week      I  (number)  I <-ranging from 1 to 52
+-------------------------+
```

Now, the idea is, that I want an array, filled with the SUM of all the products.
The SUM(Products) must exist of the following:

Sum of all products per shift + line.

Shift 1, Line 1, made 10,000 products
Shift 1, Line 2, made 15,000 products
Shift 1, Line 3, made 20,000 products (etc etc)

`SUM(Products)` will be all products from shift 1 to 3, and all lines 1 to 8.
So: 10,000 + 15,000 + 20,000 etc etc.

I want this total to be put inside an array, having 'week 1' as my array keys.

So for the first week you get:

```
$array (
    "1" => // SUM(products) of week 1 (which was the 10,000 + 15,000 + 20,000 etc)
    "2" => // SUM(products) of week 2
    "3" => // SUM(products) of week 3
// etc.
```

Can I do this by adding 52 different MySQL-Queries, with the only difference WHERE week='x'?

So far I have only been experimenting with code found on the interwebz.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D

Greetings from Holland

Comment: What is the SQL query you are currently using? I would think you'd simply return the appropriate result from that to to handled in PHP

Comment: I think you might want GROUP BY to collect the results by week

Comment: Also, there is an ISO standard for "Week Numbers."  You would probably want to check that your numbers conform.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: The current MySQL Query I am using =<br/>
mysql_query("SELECT week, SUM(products) FROM production WHERE week='1' GROUP BY week")
(For every new entry a new week. So this query 52 times)

Comment: Maybe omit the WHERE clause.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't there a simple way with some while loop?... While loops arent my best skill in PHP ... So if any of you people have an example which I can use for inspiration, that would be great..

Answer (score 1):

Just take out the WHERE clause, and you'll get results for every week.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT week, SUM(products) AS total 
  FROM production GROUP BY week");
```

The results will be returned as successive rows from the result set, and you can put them into an array:

```
$sum_by_week = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $sum_by_week[$row["week"]] = $row["total"];
}
```

PS: You didn't ask for this, but you should be aware that the mysql_* functions are being deprecated.  You should start using the mysqli functions or PDO for new PHP applications.  Only if you're just maintaining an existing application is it worthwhile to continue using the old mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance for using mySQL instead of another extension. ;-)

```
<?php // RAY_temp_rowan.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "<pre>";


// CONNECTION AND SELECTION VARIABLES FOR THE DATABASE
$db_host = "localhost"; // PROBABLY THIS IS OK
$db_name = "??";        // GET THESE FROM YOUR HOSTING COMPANY
$db_user = "??";
$db_word = "??";

// OPEN A CONNECTION TO THE DATA BASE SERVER
// MAN PAGE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php
if (!$db_connection = mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_word"))
{
    $errmsg = mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error();
    echo "<br/>NO DB CONNECTION: ";
    echo "<br/> $errmsg <br/>";
}

// SELECT THE MYSQL DATA BASE
// MAN PAGE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php
if (!$db_sel = mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection))
{
    $errmsg = mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error();
    echo "<br/>NO DB SELECTION: ";
    echo "<br/> $errmsg <br/>";
    die('NO DATA BASE');
}
// IF WE GOT THIS FAR WE CAN DO QUERIES


// CREATING A TABLE
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table (
        _key INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        shift    INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        line     INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        products INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        week     INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY(_key)  )";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

// IF mysql_query() RETURNS FALSE, GET THE ERROR REASONS
if (!$res)
{
    $errmsg = mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error();
    echo "<br/>QUERY FAIL: ";
    echo "<br/>$sql <br/>";
    die($errmsg);
}



// LOAD UP THE TABLE
mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table (shift, line, products, week) VALUES (1,2,4000, 1)') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table (shift, line, products, week) VALUES (1,4,4000, 1)') or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table (shift, line, products, week) VALUES (1,2,4000, 2)') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table (shift, line, products, week) VALUES (1,4,5000, 2)') or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table (shift, line, products, week) VALUES (1,2,4000, 3)') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table (shift, line, products, week) VALUES (1,4,6000, 3)') or die(mysql_error());


// MAKING A SELECT QUERY AND TESTING THE RESULTS
$sql = "SELECT week, SUM(products) as sump FROM my_table GROUP BY week ORDER BY week ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

// IF mysql_query() RETURNS FALSE, GET THE ERROR REASONS
if (!$res)
{
    $errmsg = mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error();
    echo "<br/>QUERY FAIL: ";
    echo "<br/>$sql <br/>";
    die($errmsg);
} // IF WE GET THIS FAR, THE QUERY SUCCEEDED AND WE HAVE A RESOURCE-ID IN $res SO WE CAN NOW USE $res IN OTHER MYSQL FUNCTIONS



// ITERATE OVER THE RESULTS SET TO SHOW WHAT WE SELECTED
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $out[$row["week"]] = $row["sump"];
}

var_dump($out);
```

Comment: Hello Ray Paseur,
First of all, thanks for your answer. The code seems to have no errors since I can run it here. But I cannot echo the array? ... I get a blank screen..

Comment: Blank screen is often a symptom of a PHP parse error when the error reporting level is suppressed.  Add these two lines to the top of the script: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);